# Getting blank page while deploying extjs6 application in liferay6?

Tags: javascript, extjs, deployment, liferay, portlet

While trying to deploy Extjs Applicaiton getting blank portlet in Liferay not sure what is the issue can someone tell where to add js file currently I am adding them in .html file also i tried to add them all in `Liferay-Portal.xml`. one more thing which all file need to add to these location i am adding `App.js`, `Main.js`, `ext-all.js`

Below are files I have added in `liferay-portal-xml`.
before this I have also tried to add all files in `index.jsp`

```js
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<liferay-portlet-app>
 <portlet>
  <portlet-name>d1523bb0-7f00-0001-4cfb-83e75e3cc848</portlet-name>
  <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
  <icon>/img/task_list.png</icon>
  <instanceable>false</instanceable>
               <header-portlet-css></header-portlet-css>
               <footer-portlet-javascript>/examplecalculator/ext-all-debug.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
  <footer-portlet-javascript>/examplecalculator/app.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
 
   <footer-portlet-javascript>/examplecalculator/theme-crisp-debug.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
   <footer-portlet-javascript>/examplecalculator/app/view/main/Main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
   <footer-portlet-javascript>/examplecalculator/app/view/main/MainModel.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
   <footer-portlet-javascript>/examplecalculator/app/view/main/MainController.js</footer-portlet-javascript>


  <user-principal-strategy>screenName</user-principal-strategy>
  <private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
  <active>true</active>
 </portlet>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean liferay-portlet.xml? Also, how does your portlet.xml look like? Which versions are you using? And: You know that you can actually format your text quite well in Markdown, right?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `<footer-portlet-javascript>`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd.html#footer-portlet-javascript) (emphasis mine):

> Set the path of JavaScript that will be referenced in the page's footer **relative to the portlet's** context path.

e.g. your `examplecalculator/` in the declaration doesn't belong there.